# How to implement Comparator using compareTo()

Tags: java

I have a class, `Card`:

```
public class Card implements Comparable<Card> {
    public enum rank {TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING, ACE};
    private rank Rank;
    public enum suit {CLUBS, DIAMONDS, HEARTS, SPADES};
    private suit Suit;
}
```

Which I need to perform two tasks on. First - ***Make the Card class Comparable, so that compareTo can be used to sort the cards into ascending order.*** I've done this here:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Card other) {
    if(this.Rank != other.Rank) {
        if(this.Rank.ordinal() > other.Rank.ordinal()) {
        return 1;
        }
        else if(this.Rank.ordinal() < other.Rank.ordinal()) {
            return -1;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else {
        if(this.Suit.ordinal() > other.Suit.ordinal()) {
        return 1;
        }
        else if(this.Suit.ordinal() < other.Suit.ordinal()) {
            return -1;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

and secondly - ***Add a Comparator class as a nested classes of the Card class called CompareDescending. This should be used to sort the cards into descending order.*** I've done this here, and it works well:

```
public static class CompareDescending implements Comparator<Card> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Card card, Card other) {
        if(card.Rank != other.Rank) {
            if(card.Rank.ordinal() < other.Rank.ordinal()) {
            return 1;
            }
            else if(card.Rank.ordinal() > other.Rank.ordinal()) {
                return -1;
            }
            else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        else {
            if(card.Suit.ordinal() < other.Suit.ordinal()) {
            return 1;
            }
            else if(card.Suit.ordinal() > other.Suit.ordinal()) {
                return -1;
            }
            else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I wondered if I've gone about this the wrong way. Should my nested Comparator class use the compareTo() function inside it? Is this better practice?

Comment: In general, if you find yourself writing the same code twice, it's a sign that you should reuse code. In this case, you're even in the good situation that the duplicate code is already nicely wrapped up in a function - so the answer is yes; `compare` should call `compareTo` :-) (Can you figure out the trick to make `compare` become descending even though `compareTo` is ascending?) That said, sometimes programming exercises are created with a specific answer in mind, and I don't know what approach your teacher has in mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `compareTo` is overly complex.

`enum` implements a `compareTo` for you, for ordering enum values in the declared order, i.e. by ordinal.

That means your code can simply be:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Card other) {
    int cmp = this.Rank.compareTo(other.Rank);
    if (cmp == 0)
        cmp = this.Suit.compareTo(other.Suit);
    return cmp;
}
```

To compare in reverse order, you simply flip the objects being compared, i.e. instead of `a.compareTo(b)` you write `b.compareTo(a)`, so a descending `Comparator` implementation would be:

```
public static class CompareDescending implements Comparator<Card> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Card card, Card other) {
        return other.compareTo(card); // descending
    }
}
```

It is a good idea to document (comment) that the comparison is reversed, because casual review of the code might very easily miss that. Here, I have documented it by simply commenting that the compare is "descending".

Answer (score 0):

You custom comparator is very complex. `Comparator` class provides suitable method to make custom comparator easier. Additionally, `enum` implements natural order comparator.

To create **descending order** comparator you do not have to rewrite existed *asceding order* comparator. Just call `Comparator.reverseOrder()` before.

```
class Card implements Comparable<Card> {

    public static final Comparator<Card> SORT_ASC = Comparator.<Card, Rank>comparing(card -> card.rank).thenComparing(card -> card.suit);
    public static final Comparator<Card> SORT_DESC = SORT_ASC.reversed();

    private Rank rank;
    private Suit suit;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Card card) {
        return SORT_ASC.compare(this, card);
    }

    public enum Rank {}
    public enum Suit {}
}
```

**Demo**

```
List<Card> cards = Collections.emptyList();
List<Card> asc = cards.stream().sorted(Card.SORT_ASC).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Card> desc = cards.stream().sorted(Card.SORT_DESC).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Shouldn't SORT_DESC simply be `= SORT_ASC.reversed();`?